# How to incorporate jquery lazy loading with ajax call in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-lazyload

I have implemented a functionality in which I fetch record by ajax call from database using entity framework in MVC 4.There are more than 2000 records comes from database and taking more time to display then I decided to change approach and now I want to implement Lazy loading approach as per following:

[**CLICK HERE**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

I have created a function in controller where i pass pagenumber parameter( and set pagesize to 10) and return result in ajax call.

but I don't understand how to incorporate ajax call with lazy loading.
Actually I pass page number parameter in ajax call.
So I want as per given below:

1) scroll down pagenumber will be increment by 1

2) make ajax call with incremented page number

3) return result will be displayed in div
and so on until last result.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your (relevant) code, so we can understand what you've tried and where there might be an issue.

Comment: I'm not talking about lazy loading in entity framework actually I'm talking about jquery lazy load plugin...

Comment: I immediately saw where I went wrong with my previous comment, so I deleted it. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Does your record contain images...?

Comment: no images.It's only return like employee name in a data table

Comment: In that case you need to use pagination because Lazy load is meant to delay loading of images in long web pages.

Comment: instead of images can't we do it for records?

Comment: No lazy loading is meant for lazy images only. Answering the way for you to implement pagination for your record to be displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lazy Load** delays loading of images in long web pages. In this Images outside of viewport are not loaded until user scrolls to them.

To implement Paging you need to Install the **PagedList.MVC NuGet Package**

Add this to your controller

```
using PagedList;
```

Refer [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) documentation for complete way to implement paging, searching and sorting.

To achieve **dynamic loading of data when you scroll** see this example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageIndex = 1;
    var pageCount;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetRecords();
        }
    });
    function GetRecords() {
        pageIndex++;
        if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
            $("#loader").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",
                data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var customers = xml.find("Customers");
        customers.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            var table = $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).clone(true);
            $(".name", table).html(customer.find("ContactName").text());
            $(".city", table).html(customer.find("City").text());
            $(".postal", table).html(customer.find("PostalCode").text());
            $(".country", table).html(customer.find("Country").text());
            $(".phone", table).html(customer.find("Phone").text());
            $(".fax", table).html(customer.find("Fax").text());
            $("#dvCustomers").append(table).append("<br />");
        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
</script>
```

for complete documentation and demo click [here](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: actually i don't wanna apply paging , I just want to fetch data when user reach at bottom of page until last record.